# How to change dataform layout on Nativescript in IOS

Tags: ios, sass, nativescript

[image: Nativescript IOS form with swished form labels.]

I have a Nativescript android app that I am now trying to make work in IOS. The issue is with the dataform forms. The Android version rendered the forms with a text label at the top and the input field below the text label. On IOS the label is rendered at the left of the input field. When I have a long label for the field, the IOS squashes the label in the limited width left text label space. Can this behavior change for IOS or do I have to do over all the forms?

I have the CSS that controls the form:

```
//forms css
RadDataForm DataFormEditorCore {
  font-size: 16;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Quicksand Regular", "Quicksand-Regular";
  // border-width: 1;
  // border-color: #fff;
  // border-color: #16315c;
  // border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40;
  padding: 10 20 10 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

RadDataForm {
  background-color: rgba(25, 48, 100, 1);
  padding: 5 0;
  border-radius: 14;
  margin: 0 10;
}

RadDataForm PropertyEditor {
  background-color: transparent;
  separator-color: #fff;

}

RadDataForm PropertyEditor:blur {
  background-color: transparent;
}

RadDataForm PropertyEditor:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

RadDataForm DataFormEditorLabel {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

RadDataForm EntityProperty[name="username"] DataFormEditorLabel {
  width: 100;
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 17;
  font-family: "Quicksand Regular", "Quicksand- Regular";
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10;
  background-color: transparent;
}

RadDataForm EntityProperty[name="password"] DataFormEditorLabel {
  width: 100;
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 17;
  font-family: "Quicksand Regular", "Quicksand- Regular";
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10;
  background-color: transparent;
}

RadDataForm EntityProperty[name="cino"] DataFormEditorLabel {
  width: 100;
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 17;
  font-family: "Quicksand Regular", "Quicksand- Regular";
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10;
}

RadDataForm EntityProperty[name="firstName"] DataFormEditorLabel {
  width: 102;
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 17;
  font-family: "Quicksand Regular", "Quicksand- Regular";
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10;
}

RadDataForm EntityProperty[name="lastName"] DataFormEditorLabel {
  width: 100;
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 17;
  font-family: "Quicksand Regular", "Quicksand- Regular";
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10;
}
```

Comment: https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/enums/dataformlabelposition.html

Comment: RadDataForm DataFormEditorLabel {
    color:#212121;
    background-color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 10;
    margin: 10;
    border-color: #303F9F;
    border-width: 5;
    border-radius: 5;
    width: 130;
    position: left;
}
POSITIOn: left/top does the trick.